# Returning Empty ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult, bad-request

I may encounter situations, when I need to just return bad request result.

For example, there is a call to MVC 3 site's controllers action, but the required parameter is missing in a request uri.

What do I return in response. I know I can do this:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return Content(string.Empty);
```

Is this the correct way for the above described situation?

Comment: For future reference, there is an `EmptyResult` type.

Comment: `return new EmptyResult();` regarding @scottm's comment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your solution will work OK, but more clear way will be using `HttpStatusCodeResult` class, like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Comment: No need to cast the status code to an int.  Just do return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

Comment: This solution is not equivalent for author's code. By default HttpStatusCodeResult causes IIS to return default HTML error page with error description, but not empty content.

Comment: @dlxeon :to get an empty result, we can use NoContent Status instead of BadRequest.  Then it should look like this. HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);