# possible to return a http request from inside an actionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using an ActionResult: if everything goes well `return new EmptyResult` if something goes wrong `throw an exception`. However as not all code paths return a value I need to add some sort of `return` in at the bottom of the function. Preferably an http request...404 maybe.

What im trying to do is Run this function from a console app ad download the PLU records to a CSV file. This all works fine, but throws an error with the 'return'....any ideas welcome

```
public ActionResult GetPLUInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            //CSV FILE of PLUs
            IEnumerable<PLURecord> listOfPLUs = _pluService.GetAll();

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\chocListWRITE.csv", true)) //true:  append text to a file with StreamWriter. The file is not erased, but just reopened and new text is added to the end. 
            {
                foreach (PLURecord _plu in listOfPLUs)
                {
                    string line = _plu.Serialize();
                    outfile.WriteLine(line);
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }

            HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();



          return new EmptyResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GetPLUInfo.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            //RETURN: How can i say here to return a http request error,
            //Using the ActionResult
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning 404 Error ASP.NET MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635114/returning-404-error-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: thanks for the answers guys iv decided to go with the personalized msg...return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "Error in GetPLUInfo");

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Response.StatusCode to a valid http error like:

```
Response.StatusCode = 500;
```

Then you can let your error handling in the web.config handle what to do, redirect to a custom action of your own or just return the page.

Answer (score 0):

Source So

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196773/returning-empty-actionresult) you can return like this

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this

```
catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```